# How to use values from previous column definition for Athena SQL query?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, normalization, minmax

My data looks like this:

```
idx,year,month,day,metadata,not_impt,metricx
123,2022,12,02,"blah blah","lah lah",-123.94
123,2022,11,05,"blah blah asd","lah lah",62.4
123,2022,12,03,"blah blah asd","lah lah",39.512
123,2022,12,09,"blah blah","lah lah",12.412
123,2022,11,19,"blah blah","lah lah",24.43
123,2022,11,26,"blah blahac ","lah lah",94.94
987,2022,12,12,"blah blah","lah lah",-23.94
987,2022,11,15,"blah blahvs","lah lah",42.4
987,2022,11,03,"blah blah","lah lah",32.512
987,2022,12,04,"blah blah kams","lahada lah",19.412
987,2022,12,19,"blah blah","lah lah",21.43
987,2022,11,26,"blah blah","lah lah",74.94
```

And they are already read into an Athena view `tablex` and there's a real number column, `metricx` that I'll like to compute some statistics in a new view, the values ranges from `[-500, +500]`.

The goal is to create a new view,

- group by `idx` and `year` and `month`
- `avg_metrix`: compute the average value of `metricx` in each group-by
- `norm_metric`: compute the min-max normalized value of the averaged `metricx`
- `errorbar_top_metric` and `errorbar_bottom_metric`: compute the [error bar top and bottom values for the 95% confidence interval](https://softkeys.uk/blogs/blog/how-to-calculate-error-bars-in-excel#:%7E:text=Answer%3A%20To%20calculate%20error%20bars,from%20the%20drop-down%20menu.),

I've tried the follow and it works but I'm not re-using the values I've aggregated when computing the error bar values:

```
CREATE VIEW AS
SELECT idx,
  concat(cast(year as varchar), '-', cast(month as varchar)) as date,
  count(*) as num_rows,
  AVG(metricx) as avg_metric,
  ((AVG(metricx) - MIN(metricx)) / (MAX(metricx) - MIN(metricx))) as norm_metric,
  
  (
    ((AVG(metricx) - MIN(metricx)) / (MAX(metricx) - MIN(metricx))) -
    (STDDEV_POP(metricx) / SQRT(count(*))) * 1.96)
  ) as errorbar_bottom_metric,

  (
    ((AVG(metricx) - MIN(metricx)) / (MAX(metricx) - MIN(metricx))) +
    (STDDEV_POP(metricx) / SQRT(count(*))) * 1.96)
  ) as errorbar_top_metric,

FROM tablex
GROUP BY idx, year, month
```

Although the SQL works, there's a few repetitions when I'm not reusing the values computed in the previous columns.

**Given that the data size is not that big < 100,000 rows, is there an cleaner way to write the SQL without copy and pasting the computation of the previous columns?**

Maybe, nested `SELECT` query?

Comment: Why do you think there is a problem with this query? SQL is *declarative*, the optimizer will not recompute an expression because it is repeated in the query text; you could define the expressions in a derived table and use them in an outer query, but that probably wouldn't affect the execution plan that's ultimately generated.

Comment: I think it's less about optimizing the query speed but just readability.

Comment: Then simply define your expressions in a derived table and re-use the aliases as you require in an outer query.

Answer (score 2):

You can talk about readability if you have an idea about the reader.
I think the nested query will make it more understandable for most readers. Reviewing the calculations step by step shows the purpose and result of the calculations.

```
SELECT idx,
  concat(cast(year as char), '-', cast(month as char)) as date,
  cnt as num_rows,
  avg_metricx as avg_metric,
  avg_min_metricx) / max_min_metricx as norm_metric,
  
  avg_min_metricx / max_min_metricx -std_err as errorbar_bottom_metric,

  avg_min_metricx / max_min_metricx +std_err as errorbar_top_metric
from(
  select *
     ,(stddev_metricx / SQRT(cnt)) * 1.96  as std_err
     ,avg_metricx-min_metricx as avg_min_metricx
     ,max_metricx - min_metricx as max_min_metricx
FROM (
  select idx,year,month
     ,count(*) as cnt
     ,AVG(metricx) as avg_metricx
     ,MIN(metricx) as min_metricx
     ,MAX(metricx) as max_metricx
     ,STDDEV_POP(metricx) stddev_metricx
  from tablex
  GROUP BY idx, year, month
  ) x
)y;
```

Execution plan for MySql 8.0
with create index ix_id_dt on tablex (idx,year,month);
There is nothing to say here without knowing the structure and size of the data.

Explain for query above

```
EXPLAIN
-> Table scan on x  (cost=0.10..2.88 rows=30) (actual time=0.319..0.321 rows=10 loops=1)
    -> Materialize  (cost=9.35..12.12 rows=30) (actual time=0.318..0.318 rows=10 loops=1)
        -> Group aggregate: count(0), avg(tablex.metricx), min(tablex.metricx)
              , max(tablex.metricx), std(tablex.metricx)
              (cost=6.25 rows=30) (actual time=0.073..0.148 rows=10 loops=1)
            -> Index scan on tablex using ix_id_dt  
               (cost=3.25 rows=30) (actual time=0.034..0.105 rows=30 loops=1)
```

For your current query

```
EXPLAIN
-> Group aggregate: count(0), std(tablex.metricx), min(tablex.metricx), max(tablex.metricx), min(tablex.metricx), avg(tablex.metricx), count(0)
      , std(tablex.metricx), min(tablex.metricx), max(tablex.metricx)
      , min(tablex.metricx), avg(tablex.metricx), min(tablex.metricx)
      , max(tablex.metricx), min(tablex.metricx), avg(tablex.metricx)
      , count(0), avg(tablex.metricx)
      (cost=6.25 rows=30) (actual time=0.027..0.142 rows=10 loops=1)
    -> Index scan on tablex using ix_id_dt  
        (cost=3.25 rows=30) (actual time=0.013..0.105 rows=30 loops=1)
```

Comment: You can throw away most of the parenthesis.

Comment: Yes, it's clearer.